# How can I reduce time to run this code?

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning

I want to find the coefficients $a$, $b$, $c$,  $d$, $e$, $k$ of the equation
$$\sqrt{a x+b}+\sqrt{c
   x+d}=\sqrt{e x+k},$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$,  $d$, $e$, $k$ belongs to $[-8,8]$ and different from 0 so that the given equation has two integer solutions (different from 0). For example, the equation 
$$\sqrt{6-x}+\sqrt{2x-3}=\sqrt{3x+3}$$ has two solutions $x=2 \lor x=3.$

I tried

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d];
sol = x /. 
   Solve[{Sqrt[a x + b] + Sqrt[c x + d] == Sqrt[e x + k] } , x, Reals];
ClearAll[f];
(f[{a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, k_}] := 
    Quiet@Check[And @@ (IntegerQ /@ #), False]) &[sol]
poss = Select[
   Tuples[Range[-8, 
     8], {6}], #[[1]] #[[3]] #[[5]]  #[[2]] #[[4]] #[[6]] =!= 0   && 
     Sqrt[#[[2]]]  + Sqrt[#[[4]]] - Sqrt[#[[6]]] =!= 
      0 &&  #[[1]] > #[[3]]  &&  f[#] &];
Take[poss, Length[pReoss]];
With[{s = sol}, 
 getSolution[poss_] := 
  Block[{a, b, c, d, e, k}, {a, b, c, d, e, k} = poss;
   Join[poss, s]]]
getSolution /@ poss
```

But, this code runs too long and I can't get the solution. How can I reduce the execution time?

For a long time, I got some equations
[image] 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you mean run the code or [`Compile[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html) it?  (See link.)

Comment: I want to run the code.

Comment: I want to run the code.

Comment: You have 6 parameters, each with 16 possible values, thus you have 16^6=16777216 cases to check. With repeated squaring you can reduce your problem to a quadratic. To have two roots the discriminant must be >0, that still leaves more than 8 million cases. You can check for integer roots of your quadratic, that still leaves 297930 equations, each with a pair of integer roots. How fast do you expect that to be?

Answer (score 7):

You can rewrite the code with `Compile` to speed up it, it really works a lot.

Firstly use `Solve` and `Simplify` to get a shorter expression of `x`.

```
In[1]:= x /. 
  Solve[{Sqrt[a x + b] + Sqrt[c x + d] == Sqrt[e x + k]}, 
   x] // Simplify

Out[1]= {(b c - c d + b e + d e + c k - e k + a (-b + d + k) - 
    2 Sqrt[b^2 c e + a (d^2 e + d (a - c - e) k + c k^2) - 
      b (-(c - e) (-d e + c k) + a (d e + c k))])/(a^2 + (c - e)^2 - 
    2 a (c + e)), 
         (b c - c d + b e + d e + c k - e k + a (-b + d + k) + 
    2 Sqrt[b^2 c e + a (d^2 e + d (a - c - e) k + c k^2) - 
      b (-(c - e) (-d e + c k) + a (d e + c k))])/(a^2 + (c - e)^2 - 
    2 a (c + e))}
```

Then write a function `cf` by `Compile` to find if a given `{a, b, c, d, e, k}` has integer solution `x`. And use this function to test all possible `{a, b, c, d, e, k}`

```
In[2]:= cf = Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}},
   (*if x is an integer, return {a,b,c,d,e,k,x}, else return {}*)
   Module[{a, b, c, d, e, k, delta, tmp1, tmp2, tmp3, x1, x2, 
     resultlist},
    {a, b, c, d, e, k} = list;
    delta = 
     b^2 c e - b d (a + c - e) e - b c (a - c + e) k + 
      a (d^2 e - d (-a + c + e) k + c k^2);
    If[delta < 0, {},
      tmp1 = b (c + e) - (c - e) (d - k) + a (-b + d + k);
      tmp2 = 2 Sqrt[delta];
      tmp3 = a^2 + (c - e)^2 - 2 a (c + e);
      If[tmp3 == 0, {},
       x1 = (tmp1 + tmp2)/tmp3; x2 = (tmp1 - tmp2)/tmp3;
       resultlist = Select[{x1, x2}, Round[#] == # &];
       If[resultlist == {}, {}, Join[list, resultlist]]
       ]] // Round
    ], RuntimeAttributes -> Listable
   ];
result = cf@Tuples[DeleteCases[Range[-8, 8], 0], 6] // 
    DeleteCases[#, {}] &; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[3]= {9.368221, Null}
```

It takes less than 10 seconds to get the result.

Comment: I want the equation has always two integers solutions.

Comment: I don't want the equation has this form `5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, -1, -1`.

Comment: You can change `delta < 0` into `delta <= 0` so that the two solutions will be different